# What is the symbol $\Bbb N$ in unicode?

Tags: notation

What is an unicode value of the symbol $\Bbb N$ (*natural numbers*)?
I can't find it via the official unicode site.

Does unicode contain it?

Comment: [This](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2115/index.htm) maybe ?

Comment: You may use `$\mathbb{N}$` to write $\mathbb{N}$ here.

Comment: Here on the site you are encouraged to use MathJax / LaTeX for typesetting. See example by Jack how to get the letter style.

Comment: Here is a [Unicode Character Table](https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character).

Answer (score 5):

A quick *Google* search for your question yields:

> [Unicode Character 'DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL N'
>   (U+2115)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2115/index.htm)

However, here on Math SE we use TeX commands (see [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) so you may plug in either:

> `$\mathbb{N}$` or `$\Bbb {N}$`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find it because it's blocked in my country

Answer (score 1):

If on a site with MathJax, refer to [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial: $\mathbb{N}$

`$\mathbb{N}$`

---

If on a site without MathJax, use [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2115/index.htm) Unicode symbol:   ℕ

`Unicode Character 'DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL N' (U+2115)`